# DataGridView looping from bottom up

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

When I run code below, the selected row returned is always from the bottom up. How can I get it to loop from the top of the Data Grid table each time?

```
'Find the selected customer by code. Display closest match in grid.
       Dim targetString As String = txtAccountCode.Text

       For Each row As DataGridViewRow In frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.Rows

            If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString().StartsWith(targetString) Then

                frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.ClearSelection()
                frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.Rows(row.Index).Selected = True
                frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Index

                Dim selectedIndex = frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Index
                frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).Selected = True
                frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.Rows(selectedIndex).Cells(0).Selected = True

                Exit Sub

            End If

        Next
```

Comment: use a for loop and use the iterator as the row index. Go from 0 to count-1 of rows. -2 if you have the allowuserstoaddrows enabled (or check to see if you're in the editrow)

Answer (score 0):

Use a For...Next loop, starting at the last row and stepping -1

```
For index As Integer = frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 ' Or Count -2
    If frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.Rows(index).Cells(0).Value.ToString().StartsWith(targetString) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other person said. (Just a bit shorter)

```
For x=frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    if frmCustomerLookUp.GSCUSTDataGridView(0,x).ToString().StartsWith(targetString) then
        'something
    end if
next
```